# Loop back through AJAX function - Causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am so so stuck with this. I have a functionA which I want to call functionB (my API call) and have it return the results of the data. The API is a "queue" and "get" type. It should run like this:

1. Run API query with "queue" type
2. Collect returned reportID
3. Run API query with "get" type and reportID
4. Collect data into myfunction

This is my current code:

```
function myfunction() {
  var ref;
  var type = "queue";
  var metric = "pageviews";
  var post = getReport(ref, type, metric);
    post.done(function (r) {
        console.log (r);
        }
    );
}

function getReport(ref, type, metric) {
   return $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            ref: ref,
            type: type, 
            metric: metric
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine. However I can't get the loop working correctly for the second part of my query. This is what I tried:

```
function myfunction() {
  var ref;
  var type = "queue";
  var metric = "pageviews";
  var post = getReport(ref, type, metric);
    post.done(function (r) {
        if (type == "queue")
        {
        myfunction(r.reportID,"get");
        }
        else if (type == "get")
        {
        console.log(r);
        }
    );
}
```

I keep overwriting the value of type which seems to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: where do you change the value of `type` from `queue` to `get`

Comment: Also, you need to add arguments to your function.

Comment: @ThoVu when I call the function myfunction(r.reportID,"get");

Comment: But even if I put this back into the function it still gets overwritten.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. Why do you want to have that recursive `myfunction` call in there? And when you do `myfunction(r.reportID,"get");` the `"get"` is simply ignored completely. Not only has `myfunciton` no arguments, even if it did, you're shadowing `type` by hardcoding it to "queue"-

Comment: This is endless recursion called stackoverflow error. Try to call `getReport` from post success.

Comment: @ChrisG I fully appreciate all your comments. The trouble is I know the problem, I just don't know how I should approach it to find a solution.

Comment: @ChrisG The recursive function call is to make the second AJAX api call to collect the report from the reportID

Comment: @Jimbob That's the thing, it's not necessary at all to call myfunction again from inside itself in order to do that. You want to call `getReport` a 2nd time, not `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic solution that chains (actually: nests) the API calls:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "pageviews").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportID, "get", null).done(function(r2) {
      console.log(r2);
    })
  });
}

function getReport(ref, type, metric) {
  return $.getJSON("report.php", {
    ref: ref,
    type: type,
    metric: metric
  });
}
```

(I'm guessing how your API works / what it returns but it should be easy enough to fit)

Comment: Thank you Chris, that's great